# How to use response.sendRedirect() for solve send e-mail

Tags: ajax, jsp, email

I use a submit form like this:

```
<form action="control.jsp" method="post"></form>
```

When i press submit button,action complete successfully. Then in control.jsp file i have an ajax request(for send an e-mail):

```
<script>
                 var email='<%=email%>'; 
                 var subject='<%=subject%>'; 
                 var comment='<%=comment%>'; 
                  $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json",
                      data: {
                        'key'      : 'APIKEY',
                            'message': {
                                       'from_email': email,
                                       'to': [
                              {
                                'email': 'to E-MAIL adress',
                                'name': 'EG',
                                'type': 'to'
                              }
                            ],
                          'autotext': 'true',
                          'subject':subject ,
                          'html': comment
                            }
                       }
                     }).done(function(resp) {
                       console.log(resp);
                       if(resp.status=='sent')
                           {

                       response.sendRedirect("form.jsp?msg=success"); // I go to where i came from with success parameter.

                           }
                     });
         </script>
```

My Problem:
If i use  `response.sendRedirect("form.jsp?msg=success");`mail don't send. But if i don't use `sendRedirect()` and stay in control.jsp (like out.print("success")) mail send succesfully.

How can i send e-mail with this ajax using `response.sendRedirect("form.jsp?msg=success")???

Comment: Why would you do that? You can do the email sending alone with java inside server side code, not only that. but you're sending the client YOUR api key in plain text!

Comment: I don't use servlet. Can i do that in jsp file? And what do i search for this give me a topic please?

Comment: Yeah, i suppose you can do it in jsp scriptlets, it's bad practice, but possible, google java email api.